# How to check the command server status of a remote Queue manager in MQ.Need shell scripting for this

Tags: shell, ibm-mq

This is for IBM MQ.I am having 2 servers with Different IP address. A,B are the Queue managers present on server 1. c,d are the queue managers present on server2. I need to check the command server status of Queue mangers c,d from server 1.I need the shell scripting for this. Please help me. If you know any commands also please let me know.

Comment: Hey Challa - Please include a list of things that you've already tried, so that we can better help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you can run a command on the same server as the queue manager resides, then you can use the command `dspmqcsv` to show the status of the IBM MQ Command Server.

However, if you are only able to run a command on a remote machine, then you could connect with an MQ client to the queue manager and put a PCF command message on the command server queue and see if you get an answer. If you get an answer then the command server is running, if you don't, it isn't.